# Website not fitting within a given screen width

Tags: html, css

I'm developing my first web application using Google App Engine. Now, while the core backend program is working and ready, I'm having some trouble working with the UI of the website. Now, the width of my website is extending beyond the given screen, which I do not want.

You can see the live version of the site here:

http://deploymentapp.appspot.com/

Now, the site is still under development, please pardon my terrible try at web designing for now.

As can be seen from the site, the width of the whole site is extending beyond the screen width.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Live Quora Feed</title>
<style type = "text/css">
*
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

body
{
    width:100%;
    background-image: url("http://www.bluelinerny.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/quora_illustration_1.jpg");
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

input.button {
width:40px;
position:absolute;
right:20px;
bottom:20px;
background:#09C;
color:#fff;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
height:30px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
border: 1p solid #999;
}
input.button:hover {
background:#fff;
color:#09C;
}
orm has no structure, no color, and no personality. We can change that with a little bit of code. First, we are going to style the form tag itself.


form    {
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, bottom, left 175px, from(#CCCCCC), to(#EEEEEE));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
margin:auto;
position:relative;
width:550px;
height:450px;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: italic;
line-height: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #09C;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
padding:10px;
border: 1px solid #999;
border: inset 1px solid #333;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

input    {
width:375px;
display:block;
border: 1px solid #999;
height: 25px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0.1, 0.3);
}

#form
{
position:relative;
left:730px;
top:300px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body bgcolor = "black">
<div id = "form">
<form method = "post">
<div>

<label>
<span>Enter your query</span><input id="name" type="text" name="rssquery" />
</label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</div>
<div class="text">
    <p>This is some demonstration text</p>
    <p>This is some more wonderful text</p>
  </div>
</div>
</form>    
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I have copied most of the CSS from another source.

How can resolve this problem?

Comment: what resolution you checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in `#form`.

Your `left` won't always be the right amount.

You need to use % instead of px.

This is called *responsive* web design.

If you want it non-obstructing the quora logo, I seem to have fixed it by changing left to 50%

[image: screencapture]

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn your css to be **responsive**. 
Instead of using **px** in **#form**, just use **%** like this:

```
#form {
  margin-top:300px;

  margin-left:55%;
}
```

There is a nicer way to have the same result. It's to **float** the form to the right and set a margin-right.

```
#form {
  float:right;
  margin-right:15%

  margin-top:300px;
}
```

Behind responsive there is much more then this, if you want to read more start from this link: http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design